# How many batteries do I need to power a 910mm long LED strip? If I want it to last 30 days, 14 days or at-least 7 days?

Tags: voltage, led, batteries

I'm using a LED strip that is roughly 910mm. The LED strip is a OEM 12V LED strip, running at 5W per meter.

My project is a LED strip that is suppose to be powered by batteries, this is to be used in a scenario of lighting up products in a supermarket for promotional and seasonal items.

So long story short I need to find out how many batteries or which batteries are the most efficient into powering my 910mm long LED strip for at least if being ambitious 30 days or 14 days or at least 7 days.

The reason behind why we need to use batteries is for the portability of the rig as it's meant to be a temporary solution not a permanent fixed product solution. I've also thought about using LED strips that run at either 6V or 3V to prolong the life expectancy of the power drawn from the batteries, but I'm not sure if this would improve it drastically. Also out of all the batteries would you say using AA, AAA, D, 9V batteries which would be the most efficient to use in this case?

My initial question is how many batteries would I need to power a LED strip roughly 910 mm long to last lets say 30 days or 14 days or at least for 7 days?

If there are any more variables or question you need in order to answer my question please ask.

Comment: The rather obvious detail missing from your question is the power requirement (watts) or current requirement (amps) of the LED strip. Can you add a link (into your post - not in the comments) to the datasheet for the strips.

Comment: E=U x I x t. You have U and t and need I.

Comment: This idea will not be practical

Comment: Average 60 led/meter LED strip is 7 Watts. For 30 days that means you need 5 kWh per meter.  
Or like 60 kg of lithium battery or 150 kg of sealed lead acid deep cycle battery, or 175-200 D cell alkalines.

Comment: It makes no sense to power it for more than one day, you should recharge or swap during the day.

Answer (score 1):

The strip will require 0.910x5 = 4.55W.  At 12V, that's 4.55/12 = 0.38A.

30 days is 720 hours.  So you would need a 0.38x720 = 274Ah of batteries at 12V.

That's a pile of maybe 6 car batteries, or around 220 alkaline D cells.

Comment: OP said "*running at 5W per meter.*", he's so far not said anything about how many meters he's going to run it for. So your answer should be "per meter".

Comment: @HarrySvensson the question says 910mm, and only ever refers to a strip, not several of them.